# Restsharp dropbox upload in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropbox, restsharp

I am trying hard to write code that uploads a file from my computer to Dropbox,
The program is running but on the Dropbox, nothing is happening. Can somebody explain to me why that is? What am I doing wrong?

```
    Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/link")
    Dim request As IRestRequest = New RestRequest("files_put/auto/{path}", Method.POST)
    Dim fileInfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo("C:\Users\rw\Desktop\logo.png")
    Dim fileLength As Long = fileInfo.Length
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "myapptoken")

    request.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString())
    request.AddUrlSegment("path", String.Format("home/{0}", fileInfo.Name))
    Dim data As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\rw\Desktop\logo.png")
    Dim body = New Parameter With {
   .Name = "file",
   .Value = data,
   .Type = ParameterType.RequestBody


  }

request.Parameters.Add(body)
Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to use the [retired](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) Dropbox API v1.

You should use [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) instead. I recommend using [the official Dropbox .NET SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet). There's an example of uploading using it [here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/b8f5c751f9df6765f4e2bbb98b39bc6bde5cfadc/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest/Program.cs#L430).

Answer (score 0):

If you or anyone prefer to use RestSharp, here's a working code to upload a file of less than 150MB using Dropbox API v2:

```
Dim sourceFile As String = "path\Filename.xlsx"
Dim data As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFile)
Dim fileLength As Long = data.Length
Dim targetPath As String = "/path/to/target/folder/in/dropbox/"

Dim js As New RestSharp.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer
Dim dropboxApiArgs As String = js.Serialize(New With {.path = targetPath & IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFile)}) ' or use Path.Combine to join path & filename

Dim client As RestClient = New RestClient("https://content.dropboxapi.com")
Dim request As IRestRequest = New RestRequest("2/files/upload", Method.POST)

request.AddHeader("Authorization", "#yourtoken#")
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
request.AddHeader("Dropbox-API-Arg", dropboxApiArgs)
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileLength.ToString())

Dim body As New Parameter With {
   .Name = "file",
   .Value = data,
   .Type = ParameterType.RequestBody
}
request.Parameters.Add(body)

Dim response As IRestResponse = client.Execute(request)

If response.IsSuccessful Then
    console.writeline("SUCCESS: " & response.StatusDescription) ' OK
Else
    console.writeline("FAILED: " & response.StatusDescription) ' Eg: Bad Request
End If

console.writeline(response.Content) ' get upload details such as rev number, etc. when successful; or else the error message
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, unfortunatelly your solution returns an error:
StatusCode: 0, Content-Type:, Content-Length:0